# Union searches through elasticsearch and spring

Tags: java, spring, performance, elasticsearch, spring-boot

Currently we are searching through elastic with multiple requests.

What I want is that, if, for instance, you have an index of fruits, with data "calories", "name" and "family", I want top 3 (calory based) fruits with family "a", top 3 with "b" and top 3 with "c".

Currently I would search 3 times, making a query look like:

```
{
  "sort": [ {"calories": "desc"} ],
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must": [
        {"term": { "family": "a" }} // second time "b", third time "c"...
      ]
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "size": 3
}
```

Using `QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.termQuery("family", "a"));`

(Being that the query above would be in a loop, so second time it's "b", third time "c")

My question is if I can somehow do a functionality similar to UNION from SQL? Joining 3 results with family "a", 3 with family "b" and 3 with family "c". Also how would this be done in Java (Spring Boot) would be very helpful!

Thanks! If the description/explanation isn't good, please tell me, I'll try to elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform a multi-search and do the UNION in Java (this is the better way so you can rank results easily).

Or, use a `bool` `should` query to do `OR` clauses.

```
"bool" : {
      "should": [
        {"term": { "family": "a" }},
        {"term": { "family": "b" }},
        {"term": { "family": "c" }}
      ]
    }
```

BUT it's hard to control how many results by family.

So another solution is to use a terms aggregation + top_hits:

(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

```
{
  "query": {
      "match_all": {}
   },
   "aggs": {
      "family": {
         "terms": {
            "field": "family"
         },
         "aggs": {
            "top_sales_hits": {
               "top_hits": {
                  "sort": [
                     {
                        "date": {
                           "order": "desc"
                        }
                     }
                  ],
                  "_source": {
                     "includes": [
                        "date",
                        "price"
                     ]
                  },
                  "size": 10
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Note: this is just an example, not a working solution.